# Developing Django with Docker

Tags: django, docker, development-environment

I am trying to create myself a development environment for a Django web app  using Docker.
My question is how should I set it up for development?

1. I've created a `Dockerfile` which uses the Django dev server and db, is that good? Or should I use separate container with dedicated web and db servers?
2. How should I create new migrations? Let's say I'm mounting the code into the container using `-v`, changes to models requires creating new migrations, so, should I make the mount writable and use create migrations from within the container? What other options are there?
3. I'm thinking about adding a `RUN` instruction to the `Dockerfile` which will apply the migrations in order to use cache when the migrations haven't changed. Is this a good practice?

Comment: I would not develop within the container. Just run the tests inside before pushing a new commit. Developing django locally in a virtualenv with `runserver` is a breeze.

Comment: Just a tip - try using docker-compose and have a `web` container separate from a `db` container.

Comment: @jcfollower Can you elaborate? Why should I use a different container?

Comment: The idea with containers is to have one app or process working in each container. See, https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container

Comment: @jcfollower Sure, but this is a single process. `manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 3):

I pretty much only use Docker to dev with python anymore (Flask dev). Virtualenvs are annoying to manage unless you use PyCharm.

```
FROM python:3.6

# Install requirements
RUN pip install django==VERSION \
    package==version

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

and on run

```
$ docker build -t IMAGE_NAME .
$ docker run -it \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    --mount src=$(pwd),target=/code,type=bind \
    -e DEBUG=1 \
    IMAGE_NAME
```

It's important to have the host as 0.0.0.0 because `localhost` does not exist in the container host file. The combination of `--mount` and `-e DEBUG=1` will allow you to take advantage of hot reloading on changes. You might need to change `manage.py` as such

```
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG') or 0
```

This is what I use when doing Flask development.

**EDIT** Kinda realized this doesn't answer all your questions

I always do multi container so I can swap out DB backends if I so please.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /code

  db: # This is the host name
    image: postgress:10.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRESS_USER=USERNAME
      - POSTGRESS_PASSWORD=PASS
      - POSTGRESS_DB=DBNAME
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:
```

You need to declare a named volume in this example `data` and you can see where it stored via...

```
$ docker volumes inspect data
```

The `docker run` command I stated earlier is basically rewritten into the compose file (since docker-compose just calls the underlying api). You could of actually started the postgress container in the background via the docker CLI instead of using compose but compose makes it a lot easier to work with multiple containers. Since there was no explicitly defined network the containers simply create a default network and bind to it. The host name for your database container is `db` or whatever you decide to call the service. So in your python files you need to use that as the hostname in your connection.

As far as migrations go I think you should just execute them in the web container. I've not really done any Django dev but if it is similar to Flask migrations I'd assume this is the case.

```
$ docker exec -it web_container_name/hash /bin/bash
root@web_container_hash# python manage.py makemigrations
root@web_container_hash# python manage.py migrate
```

**EDIT 2**

When those commands are ran it should create you migrations and since `/code` is actually bound to your local directory it will save them to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Making migrations in Django creates migration files. Should I let the container create migration files? Should the volume be read-only?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean by letting the container create the migrations that you mean executing the migrations commands in the context of the container and so I updated my answer with the actual commands and a note. Which volume do you mean (named or bound) in the context of your second question?